# How to implement HAC Standard Errors in r

Tags: r, plm, robust

I need to solve the issue of serial correlation in a within-model.
I calculated the regression with country- and year-fixed effects and then calculated robust standard errors HC1. How can I calculate HAC Standard Errors instead? I've read about function **vcovHAC()** but I couldn't figure out how to implement it properly.

```
IVpan <- plm(log(Y) ~ log(X),
             model = "within",
             data = df,
             index = c("countryIdentifier","year"),
             effect = "twoways")
covIVpan         <- vcovHC(IVpan, type = "HC1")
robust_seIVpan    <- sqrt(diag(covIVpan))
```

Thanks for your support!

Comment: It is unclear from which package function `vcovHAC` stems and if it is compatible with plm model objects. Otherwise here is the general approach as an answer to a similiar question of yours (please accept if it answer your question there): https://stackoverflow.com/a/71787457/4640346

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`coeftest(IVpan, vcov = vcovHAC(IVpan))`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Somehow, I got an error running the proposed code. The error is **Error with `estfun`**.  Do you happen to know why?